# Twos For Thought

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

**How** many twos do you need to get to the number $100$ exactly?

Example: $22+22+22+22+2^2+2^2+2^2$

This example method uses 14 twos and is obviously not ideal. Can you find a way that uses the least amount of twos? I've seen some things like this on PuzzlingSE and they've been pretty well accepted so I decided to make my own, as these are fun to do! The lowest number of twos will win!

**Math You Can Use:**

- Addition
- Subtraction
- Multiplication
- Division
- Exponents
- Square & Cube Roots

**Other Rules For Clarification:**

- The only number you may use are twos; any other numbers must be made with a combination of twos in some way.
- This problem uses base 10 and the answer should be base 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution with 5 twos:

> $(2\times2\times2 + 2)^2$

Another solution with 5 twos:

> $\big(\frac{22-2}{2}\big)^2$

Comment: Good job! This seemed to be the lowest I could get too!

Comment: @Xandawesome If factorial is allowed, then this also works for a 5 twos solution: $ ((2^2)!\times2+2)\times2 $ . Couldn't come up with anything lower.

Answer (score 3):

You never specified what base you were using...

> In base 2, $100$ means the number four, so the answer is **two** twos ($2+2,2\times2,2^2$, etc.)
> In base 3, $100$ means the number nine, which can be got with **four** twos: $\big(2+\frac{2}{2}\big)^2$.
> In base 4, $100$ means sixteen, so the answer is **three** twos: $2^{2^2}$.
> In base 5, $100$ means twenty-five, which can be got with **five** twos: $\big(2+2+\frac{2}{2}\big)^2$.
> In base 6, $100$ means thirty-six, which can be got with **four** twos: $(2+2+2)^2$.

And so on.

Comment: I'm using base 10 ;)

Comment: @Xandawesome Ah, now you've edited to invalidate my answer! :'( ;-)

Comment: Lol! +1 for creative thinking.

Comment: All numbers are base "10".  :)

Comment: @JeremyStein ROFL! Very good point :-D

Comment: In base 2, 2 doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Here's *three* twos:

> ${\left(2\over{.2}\right)}^2$

Well since it's already been bumped, here it is, using *four* twos:

> $(2*2)\over{(.2*.2)}$ as well as $(22-2)/.2$ and $22/.22$

Answer (score 0):

A solution with 6 twos and only subtraction and division:

> $(222-22) \div 2$

Comment: That makes 200, not 100.

Comment: @pacoverflow thanks - I fixed it, but now it has an extra 2

Comment: Amy B, I just gave you an approval for that amended answer.