# A Threes Of Cake

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

**This** question is similar to my other question [Twos For Thought](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16741/twos-for-thought), which arguably was a better pun but I decided to recreate the question, except with threes!

**How** many threes do you need to get to the number $100$ exactly?

Example: $3^3*3!-33-33+3+\frac{3}{3}$

This example method uses 10 threes and is obviously not ideal. Can you find a way that uses the least amount of threes? The lowest number of threes will win!

**Math You Can Use:**

- Addition
- Subtraction
- Multiplication
- Division
- Exponents
- Square & Cube Roots
- Factorials
- Parenthesis are allowed as long as they are used to order operations

**Other Rules For Clarification:**

- The only number you may use are threes; any other numbers must be made with a combination of threes in some way.
- This problem uses base 10 and the answer should be base 10.
- Decimal points are allowed (Expressions like .$n$ instead of 0.$n$ is allowed, but .0$n$ instead of 0.0$n$ is not.

Comment: As [Jeremy Stein pointed out](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16741/twos-for-thought/16753?noredirect=1#comment52423_16753), all numbers are 10 in base 10 (themselves). You should say "This problem uses base *ten*" ;-)

Comment: Problem poser, you need to explicitly state that decimal points are permitted.

Comment: They are added to the rules

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

> $(3*3)\over{(.3*.3)}$

If this counts, then these would also count:

> $(33-3)/.3$ and $33/.33$ (credit to Joe Z.)

Comment: Very nice! But is ".3" allowed as an abbreviation for "0.3"?

Comment: If you're doing it like that, you can also do $(33-3)/.3$ or $33/.33$.

Comment: I suppose this would work, and I'll count the .3 as 0.3

Comment: I'll go ahead and check this unless anyone has anything better or lower.

Comment: @randal'thor But is "3" allowed as an abbreviation of "3.0" (or "03")?

Comment: The problem poser never stated that decimal points were permitted, so I stated that the problem poser needs to state it as such if it is to be allowed.

Answer (score 9):

A quick initial attempt gives us five:

$33 \times 3 + \frac 33 = 100$

If we're allowed to put overlines on top of numbers, I can get four:

$33.\overline{3} \times 3 = 100$

The overline means "33.3 repeated", or $33 \frac 13$.

Comment: The overlines are not allowed, but the first one is good. But can you get it smaller?

Comment: I'm thinking about it right now.

Comment: Do you know of a solution that uses only four?

Comment: Not currently. I knew the five threes but I'm not sure about four. It's worth a shot though, I bet there is a way! I'm thinking too!

Comment: I think using an overline on top of the 3 is sort of like having an infinite number of 3's haha...

Answer (score 8):

If we are allowed to use an infinite number of operations, and we are limited in only the number of 3's that we use, then we can get away with using just one 3.

Since the factorial function increases the number and the square root function decreases the number, applying an infinite number of factorials and square roots on 3 in a certain sequence at some point will result in 100. If we can use any rounding function then this becomes even easier.

Another way to do it would be:
33*3+√√√... ...√√√3
(An infinite number of square roots converges to 1)

And, if what Quark answered is valid, then is 3/0.03 valid? That would be a 2 threes solution.

Comment: I've got to say, this is pretty creative! ;)

Comment: The last line works, but the middle paragraph is very woolly and unrigorous. Is that _really_ true?

Comment: Playing around and trying to prove that you can get to 100 i found something interesting: (√(3!))! is almost pi... off by a little less than 0.003.

Comment: And (√(4!))! is almost 100. Factorial square root factorial is interesting...

Comment: If we can use floor, this works. Otherwise the middle paragraph seems unlikely - if we restrict factorials to natural numbers (which isn't really a restriction so much as "the domain of the factorial" - extensions like the gamma function are not wholly natural, even if they coincide at integers), we can prove that that *doesn't* happen. The only perfect square factorials are $0!$ and $1!$ and the square root of any other thing is irrational. I would bet that even using the gamma function doesn't suffice.

Comment: @Meelo I'm not an expert in this field by any means but even if the square root is irrational, wouldn't it be possible for a result to become infinitely close to 100? Maybe after applying 9001 trillion trillion factorials to 3, it becomes a number that can be square rooted to 100.000000001. And if that's the case, then maybe that decimal can always be moved to the right with more operations.

Comment: @Quark Well, I'm relatively confident that one can get arbitrarily close to $100$ (though I can't prove it), but a convergent sequence cannot, in any case, be built by successively adding a single operation - so we need to group multiple operations into one to make a sensible limit. If we restrict factorials to integers, it is even worse: there is no sequence of operations with $100$ as a convergent subsequence. Once we start taking square roots we may never take another factorial, so the sequence passes as close to $100$ as it will, then shrinks to near $10$ and keeps shrinking.

Comment: factorial does work on all real numbers, or at least on every single calculator that I have gotten my hands on. I think the definition of the factorial is the gamma function... its up to the OP.

Comment: @Meelo I don't think you can get a concise way to express that limit, though, without using the number "100" itself which would not be allowed.

Comment: "3/0.03" is not valid, because it uses digits other than threes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one:

```
33.(3) * 3 = 100
```

This however does not follow the requirement "Parenthesis are allowed as long as they are used to order operations", in this example it denotes `0.(3)` means `0.3333...`.

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...) also marks infinite [repeating decimals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal#Notation) with a line or a dot over the number; here is the image from Wikipedia:

[image: repeating 0,3333]

which would allow to not uses parentheses, so this should count (4 threes).

Comment: You can't just use 0.(3) to denote 0.333...

Comment: Why not? I provided links showing this is a correct notation

Comment: As the problem poser stated "[parentheses] are allowed as long as they are used to order operations."  You are not using them to order operations.

Comment: Well, yes. I presented also notation with a dot over the number or a line. The decimal point is also not allowed, however it is in the accepted answer. You should rather say that I used the same solution as [Joe Z. did](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/16771/10880) (unfortunately, I haven't noticed his answer before, so I accept he was the first).

Comment: (BTW I upvoted your comment regarding that decimal point was not allowed)