# How do you get 23 using the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 5?

Tags: calculation-puzzle

You can only use Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, Division.  This is for a math project for my daughter.

You can only use the numbers once and all numbers do not need to be used.

Comment: I don''t believe there is and answer to the question as stated.

Comment: Is it possible a 4 got lost somewhere? $23=5*3+4*2*1$

Comment: Can you use concatenation? In other words, can you make a two digit number by putting two of the digits together? Like $1$ and $5$ could make the number $15$?

Comment: Looks like this puzzle is either unsolvable or incomplete. If you wanted an unsolvability proof, it would have been better to mention that in the puzzle.

Comment: Can I just use an eraser on the 1, the 5, the commas, and the word *and*?

Comment: @SarahFritz Please tell us the average age of your daughter classroom (7 years old?, 17 years old?) and what was the teacher expecting for this math project? "impossible", "usage of concatenation", "usage of decimal point", "usage of exclamation point" (factorial), "usage of power notation", "usage of non-decimal base", etc.? Or was it just a typo from teacher?

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that setting a child a maths question that cannot be solved - without first introducing the concept of insoluble problems - may reinforce any feeling in the child that they are unable to answer maths questions and are therefore bad at maths.  Such questions should be handled carefully to ensure that the discovery that there is no solution is a positive outcome for the child.

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan, that is such a good comment, it deserves to be its own post, on parenting or something.

Comment: Would the lateral thinking tag be appropriate here?

Answer (score 42):

As stated the problem is not possible. [Here's an online solver to show that.](http://www.dcode.fr/countdown-numbers-game)

Lateral thinking options could fix it (like @Apep (reinterpretation of the list), @jlars62(decimal point (very clever)), or @hoffmale (factorials), or @sousben and @D Krueger (non-decimal)). Or allowing powers:

> $5^2-3+1=23$

Or allowing concatenation.

Comment: Problem statement does not include exponentiation but still +1

Comment: Powers are not allowed: -1
No solution: +1

Comment: @ElementsinSpace: powers were used as "lateral thinking" after explaining there is no solution.

Comment: 5² is just equal to 5*5. Wouldn't this be a solution?

Comment: Per original question: You can only use each number once

Comment: This is what I arrived at independently. *Using* each number once. 5 squared uses 5 and 2. Squaring a number is multiplication. How semantic is the question? +1 - like the end of the calculation!!

Comment: You are, however, making an assumption (usually a good one) that the 23 stated in the title is base 10.  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/57085/37225 and https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/57082/37225 cleverly answer the question you "prove" is unanswerable. _Every fact_ has assumptions underlying it.

Comment: I'll add those in. Very good.

Answer (score 37):

One solution could be:

> (5+3)*3-1

under the (possibly invalid) assumption that

> the problem could be considered as using "1, two 3, and 5"

Comment: Wins the "lateral thinking" award...

Answer (score 28):

I guess we are not allowed to repeat the numbers:

> 35 - 12 = 23

Comment: This has to be the simplest possible answer. :)

Comment: concatenation is not allowed as per the OP, if it was , surely just concatenate the 2 and 3=> 23

Comment: @JasonV, OP didn't say anything about that. And you can't concatenate the 2 and 3 because you must use all those four numbers.

Comment: when OP said "you can only use Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, Division" they did not include concatenation. Therefore, this is out of scope. Also, OP did not say you must use all numbers nor only once.

Comment: @JasonV, I am sure you know that concatenating is not a part of mathematical operation. I think it is better wait and see what the OP thinks about these answers and we shouldn't talk on his behalf.

Comment: @Seyed: Actually, concatenating is a valid and well defined mathematical operation. It's just not one of the operations allowed by the OP. (if you are wondering what mathematical, rather than string, operation concat is it is `x*10+y`)

Comment: @slebetman, We all know that with those conditions there is no solution to this problem and in my opinion this answer is the closest to an acceptable solution. Other solutions with exponents and repeating numbers got more reputations than my solution :-)

Comment: The fact that the question specifies 'numbers' and not 'digits' invalidates this answer. There is no listed operator which combines the integer numbers 3 and 5 to equal 35, likewise with 1 and 2 equaling 12.

Answer (score 25):

> $$ \frac{5}{.2} - 3 + 1 = 23 $$

Comment: Please put answers in spoiler tags.

Comment: Doesn't .2 mean dividing 2 by 10?

Comment: @DEEM : Just because $0.2 = 2/10$ does not mean "$.2$" entails division ...  any more than $4 = 8/2$ means that "$4$" entails division.

Comment: Brilliant, but no.  Had the question said "digits" this would work, but the question says "numbers" and the number .2 is not the same as the number 2.

Answer (score 19):

> 23, not using 1 or 5.

didn't even need to use any mathematical functions

Comment: Specifically "2" + "3"

Comment: -1. You used an invalid operation (concatenation) that wasn't allowed in the post.

Answer (score 13):

It's very straightforward:

> `(5*3+2)/1`
>
> Or, as pointed out by Cœur, since all numbers need not be used:`5*3+2`

Why this works:

> Calculations are performed in base-7.

Comment: You can remove the `/1` as not all symbols are required.

Answer (score 8):

This is the answer, only using 2 of the 4 proposed numbers:

> 5 * 3 = 23

How come, you say?

> we used base 6 calculations

Answer (score 7):

Using concatenation:

> 25 - 3 + 1

Answer (score 3):

Using numbers more than once, but interesting sequence.

> 1*2+2*3+3*5 = 23

Comment: Given that the question is unclear as to if we can use each number more than once, this answer is plausible...

Comment: fibonacci new world order confirmed?

Answer (score 3):

If factorial is allowed:

> (5 - 1)! - 3 + 2 = 23

or

> 5 * (3! - 1) - 2 = 23

or

> (2 + 1) * 3! + 5 = 23

or

> 5! / 3! + 2 + 1

Comment: What's faculty?

Comment: I think hoffmale means factorial, or at least that's what I would call the ! operator

Comment: @Mazura yeah, i meant factorial... bad/wrong translation from german

Comment: "factorial" is "Fakultät" in German, which is basically the same word used for an university "faculty"

Comment: factorial was the first solution that came to my mind! +1

Answer (score 3):

Assuming concatenation is allowed then this is another answer:

> 13 + 2 * 5

Answer (score 3):

How about this

> (3*2+1)*5 = 23 using HEX

Comment: HEX does not sound like addition, subtraction, multiplication or division.

Comment: @boboquack Why can't I use hexadecimal, where the base is 16?

Comment: Base conversion is a way around literally any of these puzzles, and gets [quite](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16741/twos-for-thought/16753#16753) [boring](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48740/number-88-from-the-digits-2-0-1-and-7/48750#48750) if done over and over again (a couple of samples). It also doesn't answer the intended question, even if it does answer the literal question. Lastly, I argue that base 16 requires $(3\cdot2+1)\cdot5=23_{16}$, which requires an extra 16.

Comment: @boboquack Ok, new to the site so I wasn't aware that it was considered boring.

Comment: @boboquack, boring or not, the question had better state that the number they want is $23_{10}$ if they are trying to rule out creative solutions.

Answer (score 3):

[Dr Xorile](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/57028/9422) has determined that there is no solution to the problem as stated. So all that remains are out-of-the-box solutions. Some good approaches have already been presented, treating "+" as [string concatenation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57020/how-do-you-get-23-using-the-numbers-1-2-3-and-5#comment175648_57033), and [changing bases](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/57082/9422) among the best.

Here's what might be *jokingly* termed a **statistician's approach**:

You could attempt the question twice and take the average:

- 5(3+1)+2 = 22
- 5(3+2)-1 = 24

Average = $\frac{22+24}{2}$ = 23.

All conditions are fulfilled on each attempt. :D

Comment: so fuzzy math ?

Comment: @NH. All crisp. Stochastic, maybe. :)

Answer (score 2):

If we can use a number twice, then:

> (2+2)*5+3 = 23.
>  OR: (2+2)*3*2*1-5+(2*2)

Comment: in that case, how about 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 = 23?

Comment: @DanielVestøl My answer was before the OP edited the question

Answer (score 2):

(5^2)-3+1

Squaring a number is the same as multiplying it by itself, so this counts in my book.

Comment: I don't think that was the OP's intent. All other operations can be reduced to simple addition, and by breaking it down to this you are saying 5*5 which gives two 5s. If the OP says we can use the number twice, this works.

Comment: Basically the same as @DrXorile's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps,

> Round of (51/2) - 3

That is

> 26 - 3 to fetch 23

Of course, this involves concatenation.

Comment: directly "23" is simpler